# Ansible - copy between servers

Tags: ansible

I'm kinda newbie with Ansible. I have a hosts file that contains 4 hosts.

I also have a 'copymap' dictionary that I built in order to copy data (folders) between the servers (the full 'copymap' dictionary is much bigger than the example below).

```
copymap:
      - {service: "zeppelin", src: '3.3.3.3', dest: '2.2.2.2'}
      - {service: "local_data", src: '4.4.4.4', dest: '1.1.1.1'}
```

I would like to copy the data between the servers, when the source is copymap.src and the destination is copymap.dest.

I know how to iterate using 'with_items', but I'm not sure I understand how I can specify source and destination **servers**. Did anyone used the built-in 'copy' module to copy from **dynamic** remote to remote servers?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/synchronize_module.html

Comment: I've read this article and the still didn't get how to copy from remote to remote server? Let's say I'm running the Ansible from Server1 and I want to sync folders between Server2 and Server3 when there are Servers1-4 on my hosts file. I need to use the hosts file with the full servers' list because I'm iterating through different servers and different folders.

Comment: Ansible will fit for this, Eaither you need to write and deploy some service daemon which will have all machine host IP's and that will do this job. Ansible will just update the host IP's to daemon service.  Or the other way is you can use just the command (scp) with commands module to do this but its is not a good way . May be you can explain your architecture bit more details so that you would get more good solutions

Comment: The playbook I'm writing is for a system upgrade. one of the upgrade's task is to copy data if the service was on server X and moved to Y - I'm handling that with a python script that gets data about the new and old structures and generates a 'copymap' dictionary (see its structure on my original question). So the Ansible is running on all my hosts (can be 10, for example) but I want to copy the data from server 1.1.1.1 to server 2.2.2.2 (while 3.3.3.3 and 4.4.4.4 and so on are on the host file as well). I will loop this dictionary with 'with_items'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `synchronize`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/synchronize_module.html

In the `examples` section you can find samples for push and pull.

Push:

```
# Synchronization using rsync protocol on delegate host (push)
- synchronize:
    src: /some/absolute/path/
    dest: rsync://somehost.com/path/
  delegate_to: delegate.host
```

Pull:

```
# Synchronization using rsync protocol on delegate host (pull)
- synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: rsync://somehost.com/path/
    dest: /some/absolute/path/
  delegate_to: delegate.host
```